# Read an existing text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm a Java Beginner and I'm trying to make a program of reading from an existing text file. I've tried my best, but it keep on saying "File Not Found!". I've copied my "Test.txt" to both the folders - src and bin of my package.
Kindly help me into this. I'll be very thankful. Here's the code -

```
package readingandwritingfiles;
import java.io.*;

public class ShowFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int i;
        FileInputStream file_IN;
        try {
            file_IN = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found!");
            return;
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Usage: ShowFile File");
            return;
        }
        do {
            i = file_IN.read();
            if(i != -1)
                System.out.print((char)i);
        } while(i != -1);
        file_IN.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: It appears like the program is trying to find the file in `args[0]` - when you run the program, do you have the file path/name as a command line argument?

Comment: it seems that you are getting the name of the file through a command line argument `(args[0])` .. what IDE are u using?

Comment: You must past the filename as first argument. If you are using an IDE, check the way to pass the parameters.

Comment: @PatNeedham, yes, I enter "Test.txt" in the Run Config. (CmdLine Arg.) of Eclipse.

Comment: @XDProgrammer, I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: If your saying that you've added the command line argument, then it must be looking at a wrong directory. you must put the file on the root folder of your project outside the src folder.

Comment: @XDProgrammer, it works when I added the file in C:\Users\Admin\workspace\Input - Output\bin\readingandwritingfiles

Answer (score 0):

If you are just putting Test.txt then the program is looking in the root folder of the project. Example: 
Project
-src
--package
---class
-bin
-Test.txt
Test.txt needs to be in the same directory as src and bin, not inside of them

Comment: I've added the "Test.txt" in the src folder of the package, because it also contains "ShowFile.java" and "ShowFile.class". But the programs works when I added the file in bin folder. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Pass a String (or File) with the **relative path to your project folder** (if you have your file inside src folder, this **should be "src/Test.txt", not "Test.txt"**).

For read a text file you should use FileReader and BufferedReader, BufferedReader have methods for read completed lines, you can read until you found null.

An example:

```
String path = "src/Test.txt";
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: That's an another way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your folder structure is like this (The Text.txt file inside src folder)

> ```
> +src
>
>          +Text.txt
> ```

Then use this code

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = ShowFile.class.getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Text.txt").getFile());
        file_IN = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Or If your folder structure is like this

> ```
> +src
>
>       +somepackage
>
>                +Text.txt
> ```

Then use this code

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = ShowFile.class.getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/somepackage/Text.txt").getFile());
        file_IN = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tons of ways to accomplish this! I noticed that you specify args[0], why?

```
// Java Program to illustrate reading from Text File
// using Scanner Class
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadFromFileUsingScanner
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    // pass the path to the file as a parameter
    File file =
      new File("C:\\Users\\test.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine())
      System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
  }
}
```